# How can I free space in oracle mount point (/u01/app/oracle/)?

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-12c

My question is what can I delete or how can I free space so that I can log onto oracle via sqlplus as sysdba. When I execute the command df -k to see the free space in the current directory it appears to be full and on the other machine its at 52%.

```
Filesystem                   1K-blocks     Used        Available  Use%    Mounted on

/dev/mapper/rootvq-rootlv    51606140    48985496      0          100%    /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your oracle installation is on your root volume you should have a look at the DIAG_DESTINATION, e.g. `/u01/app/oracle/diag/`. If there's a lot of old trace files in there you can safely remove them with `adrci`. If your oracle installation is on a separate disk you have to check where the space is consumed (/var?) and free space there.

Comment: removing the old trace file and the .aud files did the job. Thanks.

Comment: `/u01/app/oracle/product/<VERSION>/<DB>/bin/adrci` purge